# how to create a function for created element in javaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use JavaScript to create **multiple** checkboxes to be inserted into a table. Each checkbox is in one row.
I give all of them the same name and class name.
But the problem is I can not create a function to be fired when I click that element.
What I want to do is create a function to be fired by clicking on any created checkbox.

```js
btnSave.onclick = function() {
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.insertRow(document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
var cellCHECK = row.insertCell(0);
var cellID = row.insertCell(1);
var cellNAME = row.insertCell(2);
var cellAGE = row.insertCell(3);

var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "check";
checkbox.className = "check";
checkbox.id = document.getElementById("table").rows.length - 1;
checkbox.value = document.getElementById("table").rows.length - 1;
cellCHECK.appendChild(checkbox);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
<button class="btnSave" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Comment: I do not see an attempt in the question to make any event bindings

Comment: Look up jquery button on click for dynamically generated element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your snippet that uses [native JS onclick property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) to set an event handler for each checkbox.

```js
btnSave.onclick = function() {
  // Make a new row in the table element.
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow(document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
  var cellCHECK = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellID = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellNAME = row.insertCell(2);
  var cellAGE = row.insertCell(3);

  // Create a checkbox element.
  var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "check";
  checkbox.className = "check";
  checkbox.id = document.getElementById("table").rows.length - 1;
  checkbox.value = document.getElementById("table").rows.length - 1;
  
  // Set an event handler for it.
  checkbox.onclick = function() { alert('Checkbox clicked!') }
  
  // Put it in the DOM.
  cellCHECK.appendChild(checkbox);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class="btnSave" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```